# Cron execution of python script not working like expected

Tags: python, bash, mongodb, cron, pymongo

I have a python script which is executed by cron, it's purpose is to manage messages from users to other users. These messages are stored inside a mongodb database. The script crawls through the messages, looks for the target name,
fetches it's _id from the db and stores the message data inside the users message array. After that the message is deleted from the message collection.

If I execute the python script manuallly everything works fine, but if Cron runs it the user will not be updated but the message will be deleted.

The mongodb server is 2.4.10, I know it's old but it's the latest verion which runs on a raspberry pi 2, afaik.
The python version is 2.7.x

```
# ...
# find all messages in messages collection
cursorMsg = db.messages.find({})

# iterate over every key in cursor
for keyMsg in cursorMsg:
    body = keyMsg["body"]
    about = keyMsg["about"]
    created_at = keyMsg["created_at"]
    sender_id = keyMsg["sender_id"]
    cursorUsrSender = db.users.find({"_id": str(sender_id)})
    sender_name = keyMsg["sender_name"]
    sender_id = keyMsg["sender_id"]
    to = keyMsg["to"]
    _id = str(keyMsg["_id"])

    # find the user for the message
    cursorUsrTarget = db.users.find({"username": to})
    for keyUsrTarget in cursorUsrTarget:
        print(keyUsrTarget)
        usr_target_id = str(keyUsrTarget["_id"])
        print(type(keyUsrTarget["messages"]))
        new_message = {
            "_id": _id,
            "created_at": created_at,
            "about": about,
            "body": body,
            "sender_id": sender_id,
            "sender_name": sender_name,
            "target_id": usr_target_id
        }
        # save the message
        keyUsrTarget["messages"].append(new_message)
        db.users.save(keyUsrTarget)
        # delete the message from message collection
        db.messages.remove({"_id": keyMsg["_id"]})
```

Is there a way to wait for the response of the save command or any other way to execute the delete command after a successful save?

Dump:

> {u'username': u'test', u'hash': u'$2a$10$Irwx.S5gwpOOB/gAxHPAv.Fpge9i6H.mEIh.RrAwfLp.qboZwm2sq', u'firstName': u'test', u'lastName': u'test', u'schiffe': [{u'kriegsschiffe': {u'galleone': u'0', u'karacken': u'0'}}, {u'handelsschiffe': {u'koggen': u'0', u'schoner': u'0'}}], u'messages': [], u'fresh_account': u'false', u'test': u'0', u'islands': [{u'buildings': {u'resource_stores': [{u'capacity': u'1', u'level': u'1', u'max_capacity': u'1000', u'attack': u'100', u'health': u'100', u'type': u'Holzspeicher'}, {u'capacity': u'1', u'level': u'1', u'max_capacity': u'1000', u'attack': u'100', u'health': u'100', u'type': u'Steinspeicher'}, {u'capacity': u'1', u'level': u'1', u'max_capacity': u'1000', u'attack': u'100', u'health': u'100', u'type': u'Eisenspeicher'}, {u'capacity': u'1', u'level': u'1', u'max_capacity': u'1000', u'attack': u'100', u'health': u'100', u'type': u'Nahrungsspeicher'}], u'main_buildings': [{u'type': u'Hauptgeb\xe4ude', u'attack': u'100', u'health': u'100', u'level': u'1'}, {u'type': u'S\xe4gewerk', u'attack': u'100', u'health': u'100', u'level': u'1'}, {u'type': u'Steinbruch', u'attack': u'100', u'health': u'100', u'level': u'1'}, {u'type': u'Schmelzofen', u'attack': u'100', u'health': u'100', u'level': u'1'}, {u'type': u'M\xfchle', u'attack': u'100', u'health': u'100', u'level': u'1'}, {u'type': u'Hafen', u'attack': u'100', u'health': u'100', u'level': u'1'}, {u'type': u'Forschungsgeb\xe4ude', u'attack': u'100', u'health': u'100', u'level': u'1'}, {u'type': u'Handelsdepot', u'attack': u'100', u'health': u'100', u'level': u'1'}, {u'type': u'Fort', u'attack': u'100', u'health': u'100', u'level': u'1'}]}, u'island_name': u'Insel 19', u'coordinates': {u'y': 450, u'x': 250}, u'ocean': 0, u'shape': 67, u'owner': u'test', u'_id': u'57246661e844a270258159f1'}], u'_id': ObjectId('57283a079d3a22c819ca8600')}
>   
>   Message send to user.
>   Message deleted from collection.

crontab

```
*/1 * * * *  pi ( python /home/py/menage_messages.py >> /home/log/messages.log )
```

Comment: Is it possible that there is some sort of race condition? But what I don't understand is that the script works well if I start it manually. The problem occurs when cron executes the script.

Comment: can u log the result of cron to a text file and see whats wronge. 
`* * * *  * /full/path/of/your/script.py > text_dump` , plus make sure u have the full path

Comment: Hi @ronald have you tried that? http://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work

Comment: Cron works well, the Problem is that delete is executed faster than update. I think it is a race condition but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Cron jobs run in a different environment when compared to the environment where you execute the script manually. As suggested in the above comment, you can try redirecting the stdout and stderr to a file and see, what's happening with running the script as a cron job.

Comment: I think I've found the problem , there is another cronjob running and updating some other fields in the user collection.